# Create Byte Array in Javascript form Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

I am in the process of converting some Java to JavaScript and have run across a mismatch that I can't figure out

Java:

```
byte ex[] = new byte[(38+5+10+62)/32*32-38];
```

My attempted conversion in JavaScript is:

```
var ex = new Int8Array((38+5+10+62)/32*32-38);
```

The length of the Java array is 58

The length of the JavaScript array is 77

I assume it's either the calculation itself that needs to be process differently or the Int8Array that needs to be something else.

Any ideas?

Comment: Integer division returns 3 for `(38+5+10+62)/32`.

Comment: I guess you should replace that spooky formular with 77 to make clear that Java is the one causing trouble ... (who else)

Comment: Yep. And 3 * 32 - 38 = 58 -- so there's java for you. And JS is just left to right (115 / 32) * 32) - 38 = 115 - 38 = 77. So fix whichever is "wong" ... assuming it's the JS one since you're converting *from* a working java solution per your comments.

Comment: Sounds like this question is not about Byte Arrays at all, but about arithmetic in javascript vs java? OP, what are you trying to achieve? why are you using this formula for the length of your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is due to differences in the way how numbers are handled. JavaScript uses "numbers" (64bit floating-point), while Java distinguishes different primitive number types, and in this case `int`egers are used, which means that `/32*32` effectively rounds the value down to the nearest 32 implicitly, in js that has to be done explicitly:

```
 Math.floor((38+5+10+62)/ 32 ) * 32 -38
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the issue. Thanks to the OP comments, too. Much appreicated.